# How do I determine if string has numerical value either positive or negative

Tags: python

In Python, I was trying to check `number` has numerical value either positive or negative. Like `isdigit()` return excepted result `true` when `number` contains only positive number, But run on negative number return result `false`.

```
number = "-235"
print(str.isdigit())  # return false
```

`isdigit()` is working fine on positive value but failed on negative.
How I can check string contain numerical value either positive or negative?

Comment: `-` isn't a digit character ...

Comment: @mgilson then how I can check string contain number either positive or negative

Comment: I want to get `true` result in both case positive or negative number not only positive number.

Comment: I edit my question again hope now it's clear what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just convert it to a number and compare it to 0?

```
s = "-235"
isPositive = float(s) > 0
```

Comment: Is there any way to determine in one step for both positive or negative number return result is `true`.

Comment: @A.Raza That is pretty concise as is. How much simpler are you expecting it to be?

Comment: @A.Raza If you want a function, you can do `isPositive = lambda n: float(n) > 0` which will return `True` for positive values, and `False` for negative ones.

Comment: @ChristianDean I want a function which takes input as a string and return the `true` result in case is number (+ve, -ve), if the input is not a number then return `false`.

Comment: built-in function like as `isdigit()`

Comment: @ChristianDean I edit my question again hope now it's clear what I want

Answer (score 1):

For the reason that '-' isn't a digit.

```
try:
   int("-235")
   return True
except ValueError:
   return Falsestr = "-235"
```

Note that `str` is a built in and you **should not** do `str = "-235"`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way if you don't wanna convert it to `integer` you can use:

```
number = '-235'
isPositive = number[0] != '-'
```